# How to write an "index set"

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, integers, quotient-spaces, index-notation

Imagine I have a finite sequence $\{s_i\}_{1\leq i\leq N}$, for some $N$. Now assume I want to sum all the terms of such sequence apart from the term $s_i$, for some fixed $i$. One way to do it is to simply write
$$
S=\sum_{j\neq i}s_j
$$
However, I want to explicitly write it by defining a $k$ in some set $K$ such that
$$
S=\sum_{k\in K}s_{i+k}
$$
Would the set $K=(\mathbb{Z}/N)\setminus\{0\}$ work? Any better way of writing it?

Comment: What is $N$ in $\Bbb Z /N$? Do you mean the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Are you sure about the tag "ring-theory" ?

Comment: Do you mean quotient ring? The title makes no sense so far.

Comment: Don't look for inspiration. Just define the index set with $K = \{ k | ... \}$ so your reader will know what it is without having to parse notation.

Comment: @EthanBolker what shape of $K$ would you suggest?

Comment: Go with @samwolfe 's answer - the first line if possible.

Comment: TeX note: for the set complement use $(\mathbb Z/N) \setminus \{0\}$ `(\mathbb Z/N) \setminus \{0\}` or $(\mathbb Z/N) \smallsetminus \{0\}$ `(\mathbb Z/N) \smallsetminus \{0\}`, not $(\mathbb Z/N) \backslash \{0\}$ `\mathbb Z/N \backslash \{0\}`.  I have submitted an edit to this effect. // @DietrichBurde, the notation $R/r$ for the quotient of the commutative ring $R$ by the principal ideal generated by $r$ is surely standard (though I'm not much fond of it either)?

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious (and readable) is to write
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\neq i}s_j.
\end{align}
Once in a while, this notation can become ambiguous, because the reader might interpret the sum to be over all pairs of $(i,j)$ such that $j\neq i$ (in this specific case, it's next to impossible to misinterpret though). To be slightly more explicit, you can write
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{1\leq j\leq N\\
j\neq i}}s_j
\end{align}
If you want to write sets, then I'd suggest defining $J=\{j\in \Bbb{N}\,: 1\leq j\leq N\quad\text{and} \quad j\neq i\}$. Then you can write your sum as
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J}s_j
\end{align}

Now, if you want to write it in the form $s_{i+k}$, then you have to define the set $K=\{k\in \Bbb{Z}\,: \text{$1-i\leq k\leq N-i$ and  $k\neq 0$}\}$, and then you can write the sum as
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\in K}s_{i+k},
\end{align}
but honestly this is just a confusing way of writing things.

What you could do though is define a new sequence of numbers $\{\sigma_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{Z}}$, such that $\sigma_n=s_n$ if $1\leq n\leq N$, and $\sigma_n=0$ otherwise. Then you can write the sum in question as
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\in \Bbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}}\sigma_{i+k}.
\end{align}
This simplifies the index set, but slightly complicates the sequence.